# remove occurrence values from array Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, find-occurrences

I have an array that has multiple months of occurrence so I did this method to remove these occurrences but no truthly results, I don't know what my mistake I made

```
let tab1:any=[month];
  let tab2:any=[]
  let tab3:any=[]
for (let index = 0; index < tab1.length; index++) {
   tab2.push(tab1[index]);
   
     if(tab2 !== tab1[index])
     {
      tab3.push(tab2  );

     }
     
   
  console.log("tab3 :",tab3)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected Input and Output because, question is not clear, if you want an unique month list, you can filter out the duplicate value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) Operator:

```
months = [...new Set(tab1)];
```